# Android app builds, but fails to install on Kitkat and Lollipop

Tags: android, sdk, android-manifest, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sarahahmed.imeche2TEST3"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
}
```

The app runs perfectly on Jellybean, but crashes on launch in Lollipop and Kitkat, even though the target sdk is 23

Comment: whats the error log you get?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem wasn't with the build configuration, but with the code. My OnCreate in MainActivity used a dialog box that for some reason crashed in Kitkat and Lollipop. SO, the error was a run-time error

Answer (score -1):

Try updating APIs and update the dependencies with the latest versions.

Answer (score -1):

Update All `plugin` and then `re-Build` your project

Comment: Open SDK Manager and then update all support libraries and API's the Re-Build Gradle